# Code hangs at stmt.Exec() transactions in golang

Tags: go

I am facing a weird issue. In the following code the code reaches to break point 1 but not break point 2. There is no error as well. The code just gets stuck there without throwing any error.

```
dbMaster := s.master
tx, err := dbMaster.Begin()

stmt, err := tx.Prepare("UPDATE service set status='deleted' where id=1")
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    log.Printf("Error while preparing statement: %s\n", err)
}

defer stmt.Close()
fmt.Println("break point 1")
result, err := stmt.Exec()
fmt.Println("break point 2")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error executing statement: %s\n", err)
}
```

Comment: You may want to check the error at `tx, err := dbMaster.Begin()` but I guess tx would be nil if it failed (so Prepare would panic).

Comment: Might be a connection issue with a long (or infinite) timeout.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?